# How to select Multiple Item in Dropdown and bind in textbox

Tags: asp.net

I am having dropdownlist with some values. If i choose multiple items in dropdown it has to bind in textbox in the format of

ex:

'xxxx','xxxx','xxxx'

Please do the needful

Thanks

Comment: how to choose muliple item in dropdownlist?

Comment: You put no effort into figuring out this question yourself.

Comment: If you choose multiple now via List box, what about showing them in TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can choose multiple items in a dropdownlist. Lets suppose that you meant listbox. Your selected index changed event function must be like:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            TextBox1.Text =TextBox1.Text + "'" + ListBox1.Items[i].Text + "' ";
        }
    }
}
```

Update for comma :

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
             if (TextBox1.Text == "")
             {
                 TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "'" + ListBox1.Items[i].Text + "'";
             }
             else
             {
                 TextBox1.Text =TextBox1.Text + ",'" + ListBox1.Items[i].Text + "'";
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in the output there is slight alteration i need. While binding in textbox there is comma(,) missing between two items. Help me

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I think this can help you with your requirement

http://www.obout.com/combobox/aspnet_selection_multi.aspx

When ever you select multiple items the items are displayed in the combobox itself exactly in the format you specified

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you server side server .net server side control

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

client side HTML control

```
<select multiple="multiple">             
   <option value="value">text</option>
   <option value="value">text</option>            
</select>
```